# Use Ajax get value from another page to update speedmeter needle

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is the original script I'm working with:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Dynamic-Speedometer-with-jQuery-TweenLite-Vroom/

The 'js/vroom.js' file contains the following code:

```
// select current content in input boxes on click
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function () {
   $(this).select();
});
```

As you can see it looks for user input which then changes the needle on the speedometer.

What I would like it to do is to grab this value from a page. We'll call this page 'currentnumber.php'. Furthermore, without the user inputting anything the needle will update on it's own as value in 'currennumber.php' changes.

This number must go through the 'convert kilometers to miles' as shown between lines of code '51 - 73' on 'js/vroom.js' and as seen below:

```
    // convert kilometers to miles
$('#kilometers').keyup(function() {
    var km = $(this).val();
    var kmNum = parseInt(km) * 0.62137;
    //make sure kmNum is a number then output
    if ( (km <= 195) && !isNaN(kmNum) ){
        var speedKm = kmNum * 2 - 31;
        $('#numbers').css('text-align', 'center');  
        $('#miles').val(kmNum.toFixed(2));
        $('#numbers').html(kmNum.toFixed(0));
        $('#mi-km').html('Miles');       
   } else if (!isNaN(kmNum)){ 
        var speedKm= 215;
        $('#numbers').css('text-align', 'right');   
        $('#miles').val(kmNum.toFixed(2));
        $('#numbers').html(kmNum.toFixed(0));
        $('#mi-km').html('Miles');       
   } else {
        $('#miles').val('');
        $('#kilometers').val('');
        $('#numbers').html(''); 
        $("#errmsg").html("Numbers Only").show().fadeOut(1600);
   }

    var needle = $("#needle");
    TweenLite.to(needle, 2, {rotation:speedKm,  transformOrigin:"bottom right"});    
});
```

In addition to this, instead of the needle on the speedometer jumping directly to it's position I'd like it to start from 0. This will give the effect of the speedometer moving. For example: If currentnumber.php changes from 10 to 34 to 56 over the course of 5 seconds the needle would move as follows:

0 - 10

0 - 34

0 - 56

I believe this can be controlled with the initial code which can be seen on the sample page. You can see the needle 'gently' move into position initially. Here's the code that makes that happen.

TweenLite.to(needle, 2, {rotation:-31,  transformOrigin:"bottom right"});

The question is: How do you automatically update the needle on the speedometer by calling a value from a remote page (which is located on the same server). Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You need to clarify how that data is stored on the other page.  Is it a variable that gets created when that page is loaded?  Is it just a number in the innerHtml of some element?

Comment: Yes, it's a variable that gets created when that page is loaded. It's simply grabbing a number from a database. There's no other content within the page. Just a numeric value. Thank you for the response and I'd appreciate any help on this. Spent a few hours searching for a solution with no luck :(

Comment: Add that information to the question as it is quite important.  I can't help you but I knew that additional info would be needed for someone that can.